# NLog inject context information c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

I'm using ASP.NET WebApi and NLog.
I want to add per-request information like a correlationId to my log messages. In the best case, the user of NLog shouldn't know anything about this. The Logger itself should be able to get the information from the http request.

With Unity i can use the "PerRequestLifetimeManager" to inject those information, but it isn't recommenden. I should rather use HttpContext.Items, but i'm not happy with System.Web and HttpContext.

Is there a possibility to set the information on the server and get them in my logger every time i want to log something, based on the request scope?

Comment: If you're relying on calling NLog static methods in your classes to create the logger, then you have to rely on the NLog API or do something like inject the id as a dependency. A more elegant solution is to register a logging interceptor that is wired up to your objects in the container, and your objects are oblivious to all logging.

Answer (score 0):

NLog has the `NLog.MappedDiagnosticContext` that you can use to create session type of logging variables.  In ASP.Net and WebAPI, using async contexts, you might need to use `NLog.MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext`

You'll also need to update the Targets' layouts to include this information:

```
<target layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|[${mdc:item=SomeVariable}]${message}" >
```

Here's how you'd use it:

```
try
{
    NLog.MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("SomeVariable", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    //do your work
    Log.Info("Some message here.");

    //do more work
    Log.Info("Finished!");

}
finally
{
    NLog.MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Remove("SomeVariable");

}
```

Of note, I'd like to see a better way to do this utilizing the C# `using` statement, like log4net supported.